# Build errors/warning when compiling in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

[image]

I get these messages whenever I compile something in IntelliJ IDEA. I'm relatively new to Java and this IDE so I'm not sure what exact is the issue. Is the most current Javac not being found?

Can someone please shine some light on this?

Comment: You have to tell the project where to find the JDK you're using.  If you didn't do that, you'll see "No SDK" set.  Go to project settings and see.

Comment: I've had SDK 10.0.2 set.

Comment: @Dandan642 your JDK may be corrupted, try to reinstall it.